# R comparing two arrays

Tags: r

I would like to compare two arrays. I need to test near equality among each elements . 
I am using `all.equal(target, current , tolerance = ...)`, but it's probably wrong or maybe i didn't understand how `all.equal` works.
I would like something with this behavior:

```
 a <-array(1:18, dim=c(3,3,2))
 b <- a
 b[3,3,2] <-18.01
 all.equal(a,b,tolerance = 0.1) # return TRUE
 all.equal(a,b,tolerance = 0.001) # return TRUE
 newFunction(a,b, tolerance = 0.1) # return TRUE
 newFunction(a,b, tolerance = 0.001) # return FALSE
```

Should i vectorized all.equal?
Can you give me an hint please

Comment: could you do: `all(abs(a-b) < .001)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the disconnect here is that the `tolerance` parameter doesn't do what you want. You're hoping that it will flag any individual differences that are greater than 0.001, but the `all.equal()` function works by considering the *mean relative difference* of the available entries. That is, it inherently compares everything in aggregate instead of looking elementy-by-element.

If you want an element-by-element comparison, you'll be better off just writing one directly, such as @Ben's comment of `all(abs(a-b) < .001)`, or presumably whatever your `newFunction()` does.

---

To further flesh out the nuance of `all.equal()`:

```
c <- a / 10
d <- c
d[3, 3, 2] <- 1.81
all.equal(c, d, tolerance = 0.1)   # returns TRUE
all.equal(c, d, tolerance = 0.001) # returns the mean relative difference
```

The difference in the last line with your corresponding line is that the mean *relative* difference now exceeds the `tolerance` of 0.001, even though the *absolute* differences between `c` and `d` are identical to those between `a` and `b`. Not only will `all.equal()` effectively consider all entries' differences simultaneously, but it will scale them to the sizes of the entries as well.